# TextView not appearing in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have the following layout designed to do the following.
To the left an red circle with text centralised on top of it.
To the right of this I have a text view but it is not appearing.

Underneath there will be other text views, but I have removed these to try and isolate the problem, but it made no difference.  Any ideas what I need to change to get the TextView to appear?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/redpink" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCircle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/redCircle" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtYouScored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgCircle"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgCircle"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgCircle"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgCircle"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:text="You Scored"
            android:textColor="@color/redpink" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtImpact"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Impact text"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the inner `LinearLayout` orientation to

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

In a horizontal linear layout, the `TextView` is based to the right of the `RelativeLayout` already taking up all width.

Alternatively, just remove the inner `LinearLayout`. It does not seem to serve a purpose here as there's already a vertical top-level `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Thanks but I already have a android:orientation="vertical" on the outer LinearLayout

Comment: ... and the `TextView` is in the inner, horizontal layout.

Comment: I have removed the inner LinearLayout, I have chained the TextView to include  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgCircle" at the TextView now appears.  Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` on first child of a horizontal LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add weight

try following hope this will help you

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:background="@color/redpink" >
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCircle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/redCircle" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtYouScored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgCircle"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgCircle"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgCircle"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgCircle"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:text="You Scored"
        android:textColor="@color/redpink" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtImpact"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Impact text"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```